# encrypt using BouncyCastle (java) and Gcrypt (C) gives different result

Tags: java, c, aes, bouncycastle, libgcrypt

I wrote this simple Java program which encrypt a string and output the hex value of the iv, salt, derived key and cipher text.

```
public class tmp{
    static Cipher encryptionCipher;
    static String RANDOM_ALGORITHM = "SHA1PRNG";
    static String PBE_ALGORITHM = "PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC";
    static String CIPHER_ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding";
    static String SECRET_KEY_ALGORITHM = "AES";
    static int PBE_ITERATION_COUNT = 2048;
    static String PROVIDER = "BC";

    public static byte[] generateIv() {
        try{
        SecureRandom random;
        random = SecureRandom.getInstance(RANDOM_ALGORITHM);
        byte[] iv = new byte[16];
        random.nextBytes(iv);
        return iv;
        } catch(Exception e){
        return null;            // Always must return something
        }
    }

    public static byte[] generateSalt() {
         try {SecureRandom random;
         random = SecureRandom.getInstance(RANDOM_ALGORITHM);
         byte[] salt = new byte[32];
         random.nextBytes(salt);
         return salt;
         } catch(Exception e){
        return null;            // Always must return something
    }
     }

     public static SecretKey getSecretKey(String password, byte[] salt){
         try {
            PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, PBE_ITERATION_COUNT, 256);
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance(PBE_ALGORITHM, PROVIDER);
            SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);
            return new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), SECRET_KEY_ALGORITHM);
        } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);            // Always must return something
        return null;
        }        
     }

     public static String encrypt(String plaintext, Key key, byte[] iv) {
        try {
            AlgorithmParameterSpec ivParamSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            encryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER_ALGORITHM, PROVIDER);
            encryptionCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivParamSpec);
            byte[] ciphertext = encryptionCipher.doFinal(plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            String cipherHexString = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(ciphertext);
            return cipherHexString;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }

    }

     public static void main (String[] Args){
         SecretKey key;
         //sha512(ciao)
         String encami = "This is a test pharse. Thanks!!";
         String password = "a0c299b71a9e59d5ebb07917e70601a3570aa103e99a7bb65a58e780ec9077b1902d1dedb31b1457beda595fe4d71d779b6ca9cad476266cc07590e31d84b206";
         byte[] iv = new byte[16];
         byte[] salt = new byte[32];
         iv = generateIv();
         salt = generateSalt();
         String ll = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(iv);
         String lp = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(salt);
         System.out.println(ll);
         System.out.println(lp);
         key = getSecretKey(password, salt);
         byte tt[] = new byte[32];
         tt = key.getEncoded();
         String lo = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(tt);
         System.out.println(lo);
         String outenc = encrypt(encami, key, iv);
         System.out.println(outenc);
     }
}
```

In the following C program iv and salt are initialized with the values given by the above Java program. No padding needed since the length of the text is 32 bytes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gcrypt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main (void)
{
    int i;
    char *encami = "This is a test pharse. Thanks!!";
    char *pwd = "a0c299b71a9e59d5ebb07917e70601a3570aa103e99a7bb65a58e780ec9077b1902d1dedb31b1457beda595fe4d71d779b6ca9cad476266cc07590e31d84b206";
    unsigned char iv[] = {};
    unsigned char salt[] = {};
    int algo = gcry_cipher_map_name("aes256");
    unsigned char *devkey = NULL;
    unsigned char *enc_buf = NULL;

    enc_buf = gcry_malloc(32);
    devkey = gcry_malloc_secure (32);

    gcry_cipher_hd_t hd;
    gcry_cipher_open(&hd, algo, GCRY_CIPHER_MODE_CBC, 0);
    gcry_kdf_derive (pwd, strlen(pwd)+1, GCRY_KDF_PBKDF2, GCRY_MD_SHA256, salt, 32, 2048, 32, devkey);
    for (i=0; i<32; i++)
        printf ("%02x", devkey[i]);
    printf("\n");
    gcry_cipher_setkey(hd, devkey, 32);
    gcry_cipher_setiv(hd, iv, 16);

    gcry_cipher_encrypt(hd, enc_buf, strlen(encami)+1, encami, strlen(encami)+1);

    for (i=0; i<32; i++)
        printf("%02x", enc_buf[i]);
    printf("\n");
    gcry_cipher_close(hd);
    gcry_free(enc_buf);
    gcry_free (devkey);
    return 0;
}
```

My problem is that the derived key is not the same in those two programs. Why?
Is the bouncy castle deriving function not working in the same way as gcry_kdf_derive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've now looked into the PBEWithSHA256And256BitAES-CBC-BC algorithm in the BC provider, and found that it is not compatible with GCRY_KDF_PBKDF2. The gcrypt algorithm is PKCS#5 2.0 Scheme 2, whereas the BC one is actually implementing PKCS#12.

Actually, I've so far not found a named algorithm in the provider that matches the gcrypt one, however I was able to use the BC API directly to get matching results b/w them, as follows.

Bouncy Castle:

```
    byte[] salt = new byte[8];
    Arrays.fill(salt, (byte)1);
    PBEParametersGenerator pGen = new PKCS5S2ParametersGenerator(new SHA256Digest());
    pGen.init(Strings.toByteArray("password"), salt, 2048);
    KeyParameter key = (KeyParameter)pGen.generateDerivedParameters(256);
    System.out.println(Hex.toHexString(key.getKey()));
```

gcrypt:

```
unsigned char salt[8];
memset(salt, 1, 8);

unsigned char key[32];
gcry_kdf_derive("password", 8, GCRY_KDF_PBKDF2, GCRY_MD_SHA256, salt, 8, 2048, 32, key);

for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
    printf("%02x", key[i]);
printf("\n");
```

which both output:

> 4182537a153b1f0da1ccb57971787a42537e38dbf2b4aa3692baebb106fc02e8

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be including a terminating NULL character in your count of 32 bytes (encami), which explains the differing outputs. The java version sees a 31-character input and provides a single PKCS#7-padded output block (PKCS#7 will pad the input with a single '1' byte). The C version is passed 32 bytes, including the final '0' byte. So the inputs are different.

I recommend you stop treating the NULL terminator as part of the input; instead apply PKCS#7 padding, as the Java version is doing. I'm not familiar with gcrypt, so I don't know what the typical method is for doing this, but PKCS#7 padding is a quite simple concept in any case.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. However this could explain only why I'm getting a different encrypted output but it doesn't explain why I'm getting a different derived key (I tried giving the key without the NULL and it obviously changed, but it wasn't the same as the Java one).

Comment: You're also including the NULL of 'pwd' in the KDF input, in the 'gcry_kdf_derive' call, which the java version doesn't do. Just use 'strlen(pwd)' there?

Comment: I already tried giving only `strlen(pwd)` but nothing changed. At this point I think that the key derivation method used by Java is different by the one used by Gcrypt. Although this is very strange because it's a standard the PBKDF2-PKCS#5...